# How do I get my Arduino Mega 2560 registered as a game controller?

Tags: arduino

I'm tempted to buy an Arduino Leonardo, but I already own an Arduino Mega 2560. I understand that the Leo already has support USB HID.

I'm just wondering if there's a fairly easy way to get my 2560 registered as an HID joystick instead, or should I rather go about getting an Arduino Leonardo?

Comment: Look at V-Usb, a software usb implementation for attiny and atmega processors, which can do USB HID Gamepads. Simple.

Comment: The following project on GitHub seems like a possible solution: https://github.com/harlequin-tech/arduino-usb

Answer (score 2):

You would need to either:

- Change the firmware of the USB interface chip on the Mega2560 to act as an HID game controller.  There's a second ISP connector for that purpose.
- Run a software USB emulation on the main ATMEGA cpu and have that be a game controller.  You would need an additional USB connector and supporting passives to approximate the electrical interface.
- Add some additional USB interface
- Write a driver for the host operating system that accepts input over CDC USB serial and injects it into the operating system as if it were from an HID game controller
- Modify the client programs to take serial data instead

Comment: Neither of these sound easy at all! ;) Especially when you're still learning.